# Angular2+ Unit Test a Service with a built in Serverservice

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, server

I'm trying to write Unit tests for the first time. Up to now I was able to write tests for "normal"/intern services. Now I'm stuck with a more complex Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseToolsService {

vehicles: Array<Vehicle>;
tools: BehaviorSubject<Array<Tool>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Tool>>(undefined);
noBaseTools: BehaviorSubject<Array<Tool>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Tool>>(undefined);
vehiclesWithBaseTools: BehaviorSubject<Array<VehicleBaseToolsModel>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<VehicleBaseToolsModel>>(undefined);

constructor(private readonly toolService: ToolService,
            private readonly vehicleService: VehicleService,
            private readonly notificationService: NotificationService) {
    forkJoin([this.toolService.getTools('Asset,ToolType'),
        this.vehicleService.getVehicles('Asset,VehicleModel')]).subscribe(results => {
        this.tools.next(results[0]);
        this.vehicles = results[1];
        this.filterToolsAndConvertVehicles();
    });
} 

...
```

My setup of the Unit test so far is:

```
import {BaseToolsService} from './base-tools.service';
import {ToolService} from '../../../../core/services/api/tool.service';
import {VehicleService} from '../../../../core/services/api/vehicle.service';
import {NotificationService} from '../../../../core/services/intern/notification/notification.service';
import {async, getTestBed, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

    describe('Service: BaseToolsService', () => {

        let service: BaseToolsService;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    ToolService,
                    VehicleService,
                    NotificationService,
                    BaseToolsService
                ]
            });
            const testBed = getTestBed();
            service = testBed.get(BaseToolsService);
        }));

    ...
    // Some Tests
```

The Problem is that the Services `ToolService` and `VehicleService` try to get a server respond. Since they are built in the `BaseToolsService` I don't know how to mock the server request/backend or how to mock the required data itself and prevent the services to reach out for the server. When I run the test it of course fails with the error `Failed: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`.

Is there a way I can mock the server respond which is one level deeper than the service is i want to test? Or is the Problem somewhere else? (Since I'm new to Unit Tests I doubt I did everything correct)

Comment: Just mock `BaseToolsService`'s collaborators, replace them with ones that *don't* make requests. When you're testing the services that *do* make requests directly, mock out the http client per the documenation: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests. There's also general testing guidance: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: Or, alternatively, don't mock the whole service but spy the methods and return an ```of(data)``` instead of whatever the service would return. Check out jasmine spy of this.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jonrsharpe, it just felt wrong to me to overwrite classes. But I guess that's the way to go.